# Redis Lua script - HMGET returned bulk contains nil but is not recognized as nil

Tags: redis, lua

Sorry for the vague title. Hopefully the examples below explain my confusion.

Try evaluating each of the four Lua scripts below in Redis. My question is why the [ternary operation](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TernaryOperator) that sets a value to 0 if `HMGET` returns nil doesn't work in the 4th script.

```
local bulk = {nil,nil,nil}
return bulk[1] -- nil (good)

-- Proof that ternary operator works
local bulk = {nil,nil,nil}
local rate = (bulk[1] == nil and 0 or bulk[1])
return rate -- 0 (good)

-- Proof that first element in HMGET results is nil
local bulk = redis.call('hmget', 'k1', 'f1', 'f2')
return bulk[1] -- nil (good)

-- Why does ternary op fail on HMGET results?
local bulk = redis.call('hmget', 'k1', 'f1', 'f2')
local rate = (bulk[1] == nil and 0 or bulk[1])
return rate -- nil (bad, want 0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `bulk[1]` is `false`, NOT `nil`.

From the [doc](https://redis.io/commands/eval#conversion-between-lua-and-redis-data-types):

> Redis Nil bulk reply and Nil multi bulk reply -> Lua false boolean type

In Redis, `HMGET` returns *Nil reply* for the second field, i.e. `bulk[1]`, and it's converted to `false` when the reply is passed to Lua. So your 4th script doesn't work, since `bulk[1] == nil` is `false`.

> Lua boolean false -> Redis Nil bulk reply.

In your 3rd script, `bulk[1]` of type `false`, is returned, and Redis convert `false` to a *Nil reply*

Comment: Wow, thanks! I skimmed through that "EVAL - Redis" doc once before and didn't think of it when debugging this. Follow-up question: in the 4th script, what's the recommended way to identify that Redis returned `bulk[1] = nil`, and thus we should assign `0` to `rate?

Comment: Check if `bulk[1]` is `false`. Also, since you're trying to return a number, you should convert `bulk[1]` to number before returning: `local rate = (bulk[1] == false and 0 or tonumber(bulk[1]))`